# Jquery find an anchor link with the href of another item's id

Tags: jquery

Trying to find an element with jquery and have hit a roadblock.

I have a variable with another elements id stored in it. I am trying to find the corresponding anchor link with that stored variable as it's href. Then get the anchor link(href) directly before that anchor.

So basically finding the list item anchor link previous to the list item anchor link with the id of the displayed div

.html

```
<li><a href="#example" class="links">example</a></li>
<li><a href="#example1" class="links">example</a></li>
<li><a href="#example2" class="links">example</a></li>
<li><a href="#example3" class="links">example</a></li>

<div id="example" class="divs"> random stuff </div>
<div id="example1" class="divs open"> random stuff </div>
<div id="example2" class="divs"> random stuff </div>
<div id="example3" class="divs"> random stuff </div>
```

.js

```
$('.previous').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var exampleId = $('.divs.open').attr('id');
    var anchorPrev = $('.links').find('href');
});
```

Comment: and the question/problem is ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('.previous').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var exampleId = $('.divs.open').attr('id');
    var selector = "a.links[href='#" + exampleId + "']";
    var link = $(selector);
    var prev = link.parent().prev().find('a.links');    
});
```

What that does is tell jQuery to find an anchor tag with the specified value of it's `href` attribute.

You can see the docs here: http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

*EDIT* Ok I see. I've edited the code sample above to reflect the original question regarding getting the previous link. Note however that this won't really work for the first element in the list.

The problem is that your `a` tags are children of `li` tags. So calling `prev()` directly on the `a` won't work as it has no siblings. However, the parent `li` tag *does* have siblings, so you can call `prev()` on that and then get the `a.links` element contained within.

Here's a jsFiddle that I whipped up to test: http://jsfiddle.net/kHnju/

Comment: I don't think this is the right. I'm pretty sure OP wants the previous element, not the currently open one. Also, why use find like that when you can just grab the `.eq()` of the element as they're the exact same?

Comment: Pretty sure he wants the `a.links` that has the `href` that corresponds to the `id` of the current `.open` element.

Comment: Could you then advise me as to how `Then get the anchor link(href) directly before that anchor.` plays into that?

Comment: You were right. I misread the original question and have edited my answer.

Comment: That does get me the current divs corresponding anchor link. How do i search backwards in the list elements to get the previous item. I have been trying with the .prev jquery code however does not appear to be working for me.

Comment: @user1881482 I added some more explanation to my answer.

Comment: Works great. Thanks i was really stuck on that .parent issue, was totally misreading my own code. Thanks again

Comment: Not a problem, I'm happy to help!